# Refresh only one region instead of the whole page in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have made a region containing 2 display only items and a button.

The button performs some dynamic action (execute pl/sql query) and the page is refreshed every time the button is pressed (submit page action) .

Is there any way that on click of the button only that particular region gets refreshed instead of the whole page?

Also for the display only items, lets say

```
item_label ==> item_display_value
```

how to add this (==>) symbol in between?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is submitted, then it will refresh completely - that is how apex works. But if a submit is not needed, you can add an action of "refresh" to the dynamic action and remove the submit. Make sure the "Behaviour > Action" property of the button is set to "Defined by dynamic action".
Note that not all region types support refresh, but all report types do.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it is not working for these display only items. Thanks though. Another questin:  for these display only items eg:  item_label ==> item_display_val, how to add this (==>) symbol in between the item label and its display value

Comment: Include that into the label itself ... e.g. `Employee name ==>`